# How to add custom CSS/JS to Grails 2.4.x layouts/templates?

Tags: javascript, css, grails, asset-pipeline

Grails 2.4.5 here, where I *believe* (correct me if I'm wrong) the `asset-pipeline` plugin is the default/desired method for managing CSS/JS resources.

I have some custom CSS/JS files that I would like to be included on a large subset of my GSP pages, and was wondering how to add them:

1. Using the `asset-pipeline` plugin; but...
2. In such a way that I can (somehow) reference them from `grails-app/views/layouts/special.gsp`, and then reference that `special.gsp` layout inside each desired GSP page.

So again, the desired functionality is:

```
grails-app/views/layouts/special.gsp:
-------------------------------------
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title><g:layoutTitle default="My app!"/></title>
        <asset:stylesheet src="my-custom.css"/>
        <g:layoutHead/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <g:layoutBody/>
        <asset:javascript src="my-custom.js"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

And then, in any GSP page that I want to use this layout, I just add a `<meta name="layout" content="special">` in the `<header>` tag like normal.

**How can I use `asset-pipeline` and layouts in concert with each other?** Where do I place `my-custom.css` and `my-custom.js`? Any special instructions here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were to leave your `special.gsp` AS-IS:

- You would place the `my-custom.css` within the `grails-app\assets\stylesheets` folder
- You would place the `my-custom.js` within the `grails-app\assets\javascripts` folder

Depending on your IDE, the `assets` folder may be at the top-level and the fact that it is located within `grails-app` may be abstracted.  For instance, using the 'Project Explorer' view within GGTS, there is an `assets` folder directly under my project.

With the asset-pipeline, you could also include these files within a 'parent' file with this syntax:

```
//= my-custom.js
```

or

```
/*
*= require my-custom.css
*/
```

This 'parent' file though would need to be included within the layout just like you have done.

**Additional info:**
I mentioned `require_self` and `require_tree` in a comment below, I'll go into further detail about their use.

**require_self**

*myLayout.gsp*

`<asset:javascript src="myParent.js"/>`

*myParent.js*

```
//= myCustom.js
//= require_self
console.log("This code runs because of the require_self and after myCustom.js");
```

*myCustom.js*

```
console.log("My require_self is optional because I'm not using the asset-pipeline.");
```

The `require_self` is used to include js/css that exists within the particular file; it is required for files that are using the asset-pipeline to import other js/css files.  It is optional when the file is strictly js/css that has already been imported.  This is the reason that you can use the `asset-pipeline` to import files that you haven't modified (jquery.js for example), otherwise you would need to place `require_self` within all files.

**require_tree**

*Directory Structure*

```
grails-app/assets/
   |
   +--javascripts/
   |   |
   |   +--js-parent.js
   |   |
   |   +--myCustomJs
   |      |
   |      +--script1.js
   |      |
   |      +--script1.js
   |
   +--stylesheets/
       |
       +--css-parent.css
       |
       +--myCustomCss
          |
          +--sheet1.css
          |
          +--sheet2.css
          |
          +--sheet3.css
```

*myLayout.gsp*

```
<asset:javascript src="js-parent.js"/>
<asset:stylesheet src="css-parent.css"/>
```

*js-parent.js*

```
//= require_tree myCustomJs
```

*csss-parent.css*

```
/*
*= require_tree myCustomCss
*/
```

There you go, now you have all 3 css files and 2 js files pulled in just using their parents and the `require_tree` syntax.

Comment: Thanks @tylerwal (+1) - a few quick followup questions if you don't mind: (1) is the special "parent" syntax (e.g. `//= my-custom.js`) specific to the resource type? Meaning do I **have** to use `/* *= require my-custom.css */` or could I use `//= my-custom.css`? And (2) If I wanted to use this parent syntax, can you just confirm that I would add a single 1-liner inside `special.gsp` of something like `<asset:javascript src="css-parent.css"/>` and then inside `grails-app/assets/stylesheets/css-parent.css` I would have 1 entry for each CSS file? Thanks again!

Comment: 1) Yes, the syntax within the js or css files is specific for the type.  This is important because `//= something` would not be valid css because css comments are only in `/* something */` blocks.

2) I believe you have 2 correct, although your example `<asset:javascript src="css-parent.css"/>` should probably `<asset:stylesheet src="css-parent.css"/>`, but I think that was just a mistake.  Within the `css-parent.css`, you could have each css file individual or could include multiple js/css files within the same directory using this syntax:

`require_tree folderName`

Comment: You would also need to `require_self` if you intend to have the css or js within the parent file.  At first glance, it seems silly to have to include something that you've already included, but it allows you to control the order of code (since asset-pipeline will bundle the files together in non-development environments).

Comment: Thanks again @tylerwal (+1 for both comments) - you're sooo close to a green check! Not to be a pain, but any chance you could update your answer with a working example that explains this `require_self` and `require_tree folderName` business? Let's pretend that I want `css-parent.css` to pull in `sheet1.css`, `sheet2.css` and `sheet3.css`. And let's pretend that we want `js-parent.js` to pull in `script1.js` and `script2.js`. What would their contents look like? Thanks again!